# POST Request to Jira REST API using Oauth Header - Responds with 401 "Anonymous User" Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth, jira, jira-rest-api

I am building a web application which will have a form to submit bug reports. The bug submission form, when submitted, fires off an HTTP POST request to a JIRA instance using the **jira/rest/api/2/issue** endpoint to create a single issue based on what the user has entered into the form.

I've authenticated my application against the JIRA instance and obtained an Oauth bearer token to include in my HTTP request headers. However, when this POST request is fired, I receive a 401 error with the following error message:

> Anonymous users do not have permission to create issues in this project. Please try logging in first.

I'm not sure why the JIRA server considers this request Anonymous, since the request contains the "Authorization" header with an Oauth token included, which I believe should authenticate the request as a certain user. But perhaps I am misunderstanding the relationship between the Oauth token and the JIRA instance.

This is what the function that fires off the request looks like (using React):

```
  submitBug() {
    var jira_create_issue_api_url = "https://placeholder.org/jira/rest/api/2/issue";
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open("POST", jira_create_issue_api_url, true); //async POST to API resource

    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "no-check");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <oauth token here>");

    xhttp.onload = () => {
      console.log("JIRA REST API responded: ");
      console.log(xhttp.status);
      console.log(xhttp.response);
    };

    var summary_text = this.props.bug_summary; //filled out by user in form
    var desc_text = this.state.bug_description; //filled out by user in form

    var bug_data = {
      fields: {
        project: {
          key: "KEY"
        },
        summary: summary_text,
        description: desc_text,
        issuetype: {
          name: "Bug"
        }
      }
    };
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(bug_data)); 
  }
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated! I'm new to developing with the JIRA REST API so I may be missing something obvious.

**Edit**: As requested, the headers as they appear in Chrome:

> Accept: application/json
>
> Authorization: Bearer [oauth token here]
>
> Content-type: application/json
>
> Origin: [app url]
>
> Referer: [app url]
>
> User-Agent: [browser-specific info]
>
> X-Atlassian-Token: no-check

Comment: Add the actual headers sent by your request. Chrome debugger is helpful for this.

Comment: Assuming you meant the request headers (rather than the response headers), I've added those to the post now.

Comment: You have not show the steps on how you obtained the token, or if you have authorized it. My guess is that you are passing an invalid token in your Authorization header and Jira is just returning an error message that does not tell you the real problem (typical security reasons).

Comment: Agree with what @JohnHanley said. Maybe you don't request the correct scopes when getting the token.

Answer (score 0):

In Jira Cloud you need an API Key.

1. Create an API key here
   https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens
2. The authorization header should be:

Authorization: Basic [base64string]

Where base64 string is the following string converted to base64:

email:apikey